# Efficiency/Memory consumption of a large Flux stream to Collection

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, spring-webclient

I am trying to come up with the best way to handle a rather large `Flux<String>` stream (5-10 million strings). This mainly consists of some simple logic that generates 8 digit number strings and then stores them into a database using a JDBC repository. Here are a few implementations:

```
    // Scenario 1
    List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    Flux.range(10000000, 18000000) // Sample code, but this would in reality be from a REST API call with WebClient
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()) // Run on elastic thread pool
            .map(Object::toString)
            .doOnNext(numbers::add)
            .doFinally(signal -> {
                // Perform some transactional JDBC operations w/ numbers
            });

    // Scenario 2
    Flux.range(10000000, 18000000) // Sample code, but this would in reality be from a REST API call with WebClient
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()) // Run on elastic thread pool
            .map(Object::toString)
            .collectList()
            .doOnNext(numbers -> {
                // Perform some transactional JDBC operations w/ numbers
            });

    // Scenario 3
    List<String> numbers = Flux.range(10000000, 18000000) // Sample code, but this would in reality be from a REST API call with WebClient
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()) // Run on elastic thread pool
            .map(Object::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .block(); // Yes, I know this is bad practice

    // Perform some sort of transactional JDBC operations w/ numbers

    // Scenario 4
    Flux.range(10000000, 18000000) // Sample code, but this would in reality be from a REST API call with WebClient
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()) // Run on elastic thread pool
            .map(Object::toString)
            .buffer(1000) // Could further tweak this
            .doOnNext(numbers -> {
                // Perform some JDBC operations w/ numbers
            })
            .then(); // Signal for completion
```

Question:

1. Is scenario 1 and 2 more efficient? Would one require more memory than the other? From a code cleanliness standpoint, 2 seems to be a cleaner way to do it, but I don't know if it is any more efficient.
2. How much of an additional materialization cost for scenario 3 if you were to just `.collect(Collectors.toList())`. (i.e. would converting a Flux stream to a List require more resources/memory versus handling a Flux<List> I suspect this is equivalent to `collectList()`.
3. Would scenario 4 be a better approach? I could try a largerlarger batch size, but I'm not sure how large of a list `repository.addAll` can handle. That would require some more testing. Setting the buffer at 1000 seems to reduce memory usage but quite a bit, but it also doubles the runtime compared to scenarios 1-3.

What would be the best approach to this problem to find a good compromise between memory usage and runtime? TYIA

Comment: What do you mean by "materialization cost".

Comment: Sorry, I have re-worded the question for clarity. I was thinking of materialization cost in terms of the memory thats required to process that large data set all at once as opposed to doing it in batches.

https://www.baeldung.com/java-return-stream-collection (see 3.1)